# Pass or Fail Case statement for MySql

Tags: mysql, case

Im using Toad for MySQL and am tryign to create a query that will tell me if the returned records pass or fail in any categories, such that i can then tell the user to correct them.

The results of my current query are this:

ID  uat_resource    risks   training    load_performance    pay_associated
1839
1846    John Flood  None    None    None    None
1849    Matt Burr   N/A Matt Burr   N/A N/A

I want to set it up so that when anything is Null it is considered a Fail, and if Risks are n/a or none then it also fails as there are always risks.

```
SELECT cr.ID,
   cr.risks,
   cr.training,
   cr.load_performance,
   cr.pay_associated
FROM requests.requests cr
WHERE cr.id IN (SELECT di.change_request_id
                   FROM dcs_item di
                  WHERE di.current_level = 3)
   AND cr.production_dt IN ('2012/01/10','2011/01/11')
ORDER BY ID;
```

I was trying to do something like this....

```
SELECT cr.ID,
   (case when lower(cr.uat_resource) in ('','n/a','none') then
   'FAIL' else 'PASS') as Test,
   cr.risks,
   cr.training,
   cr.load_performance,
   cr.pay_associated
FROM requests.requests cr
WHERE cr.id IN (SELECT di.change_request_id
                   FROM dcs_item di
                  WHERE di.current_level = 3)
   AND cr.production_dt IN ('2012/01/10','2011/01/11')
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: and what were your results?  Did it error, give you the wrong data?

Answer (score 0):

You need an "end" to your case statement:

```
SELECT cr.ID,
   (case when lower(cr.uat_resource) in ('','n/a','none') then
   'FAIL' else 'PASS' END) as Test,
   cr.risks,
   cr.training,
   cr.load_performance,
   cr.pay_associated
FROM requests.requests cr
WHERE cr.id IN (SELECT di.change_request_id
                   FROM dcs_item di
                  WHERE di.current_level = 3)
   AND cr.production_dt IN ('2012/01/10','2011/01/11')
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just had that brain fart and realized that.   guess its just been a looong week. :)